Is the strong ultrafilter topology countably paracompact?
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
We start with the relevant definitions:
Definition: A topological space $X$ is called paracompact if every open cover of $X$ admits a locally finite open refinement. Recall that for a Hausdorff space $X$, $X$ is paracompact iff for any given open cover of $X$, there is a partition of unity subordinate to it. A topological space $X$ is called countably paracompact if every countable open cover of $X$ admits a locally finite open refinement.
Definition: The strong ultrafilter topology has underlying set $X = \omega \cup M$ where $M$ is the collection of all free ultrafilters on $\omega$. The topology is generated by the basis consisting of $\{n\}$ for $n \in \omega$ and $A \cup \{F\}$ for $A \in F \in M$.
We remark here that the strong ultrafilter topology has the same underlying set as $\beta\omega$, the Stone-Čech compactification of $\omega$. Moreover, the topology is easily seen to be strictly finer than that of $\beta\omega$. We remark here that $X$ is, as opposed to $\beta\omega$, not compact. The easiest way to see this is simply to note that there is no compact topology strictly finer than a compact Hausdorff topology. It is actually even the case that $X$ is not countably compact. Indeed, partition $M$ into countably infinitely many nonempty disjoint sets $M = \bigcup_n M_n$. Then $\{\omega \cup M_n\}_n$ is a countable open cover of $X$ that admits no finite subcover.
On the other hand, $X$ is pseudocompact, i.e., any continuous $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Indeed, the definition of topology ensures that $f(F) = \lim_{n \to F} f(n)$ for every $F \in M$, so $f$ is actually continuous as a function $\beta\omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $\beta\omega$ is compact, the range of $f$ is thus bounded. This implies $X$ cannot be paracompact, as every Hausdorff paracompact pseudocompact space is compact. (For a sketch of the proof, assume to the contrary that there is a Hausdorff paracompact pseudocompact $Y$ that is not compact. Then let $\{U_i\}$ be an open cover of $Y$ with no finite subcover. Let $\{f_i\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_i\}$. Inductively choose $x_n \in X \setminus \left(\bigcup_{m < n} U_{i_m}\right)$, $f_{i_n} \in \{f_i\}$ s.t. $f_{i_n}(x_n) > 0$, and $U_{i_n} \in \{U_i\}$ which contains the support of $f_{i_n}$. One then observes that $f(x) = \sum_n \frac{nf_{i_n}(x)}{f_{i_n}(x_n)}$ is an unbounded continuous function $Y \to \mathbb{R}$, contradicting pseudocompactness of $Y$.)
However, this proof is indirect. Moreover, it leaves open the question as to whether $X$ is countably paracompact, which is currently unknown on pi-Base as well.

Is $X$, the strong ultrafilter topology, countably paracompact?


$X$ is not countably paracompact. We'll show this by proving that any locally finite open cover of $X$ is actually finite, from which it follows that, were $X$ countably paracompact, it would also be countably compact, a contradiction.
We first recall that $\beta\omega$ can be regarded as the Stone space of the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, from which it follows that the topology on $\beta\omega$ is generated by the basis $V(A) = A \cup \{F \in M: A \in F\}$ for $A \subset \omega$. Now, let $\{U_i\}$ be a locally finite open cover of $X$. For each $F \in M$, by defintion of the topology on $X$ and the fact that $\{U_i\}$ is locally finite, there exists $A_F \in F$ s.t. $A_F \cup \{F\}$ intersects only finitely many $U_i$.
Now, $\{\{n\}: n \in \omega\} \cup \{V(A_F): F \in M\}$ is an open cover of $\beta\omega$. Since $\beta\omega$ is compact, it admits a finite subcover, i.e., there exists $n_1, \cdots, n_p \in \omega$ and $F_1, \cdots, F_q \in M$ s.t. $\{n_1, \cdots, n_p\} \cup \left(\bigcup_{l = 1}^q V(A_{F_l})\right) = \beta\omega = X$. Hence, any (nonempty) $U_i$ must either

contain $n_l$ for some $1 \leq l \leq p$. Since $\{U_i\}$ is locally finite, there are only finitely many $U_i$ that satisfy this;
intersect $V(A_{F_l})$ for some $1 \leq l \leq q$. Note that $V(A_{F_l})$ is also open in $X$, so $U_i \cap V(A_{F_l})$ is nonempty open. Since $\omega \subset X$ is dense, we have $\omega \cap U_i \cap V(A_{F_l}) = U_i \cap A_{F_l}$ is nonempty. Thus, $U_i$ intersects $A_{F_l} \cup \{F_l\}$. From the choice of $A_F$, it follows that there are only finitely many $U_i$ that satisfy this condition as well.

This shows there are only finitely many $U_i$ and the proof is complete.
